# retrieve text of element with XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to retrieve a text of an element with xslt but I couldn't do that.would you please tell me which part of my code is false?
my xslt file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="zoo">
    <html>
      <title>
        <xsl:text>ZOO</xsl:text>
      </title>
      <head>
        <h1>Behausung im Zoo "Zoogarten"</h1>
      </head>
      <p>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="zootier" />
      </p>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="zootier">
    <xsl:for-each select="zoo/zootier" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

is'nt this part of code correct to retrieve text of element?

this is my sample xml file:

```
<zoo   name="zoogarten">
  <zootier  id="tier1" flugfaeghig="false">
    <name>erna</name>
    <alter>2</alter>
    <schlachtgewicht>1500</schlachtgewicht>
  </zootier>
  <zootier id="tier2"  schimmel="false">
    <name>peter</name>
    <alter>4</alter>
    <tragezeit>11</tragezeit>
  </zootier>
  <zootier id="tier3" >
    <name>minka</name>
    <alter>3</alter>
    <tragezeit>2</tragezeit>
    <fellfarbe>hell</fellfarbe>
  </zootier>
   .....
```

Comment: Is that `<xsl:text>ZOO</xsl:text>` part where you're trying to extract something from the XML?

Comment: no this part:`<xsl:template match="zootier">
    <xsl:for-each select="zoo/zootier" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>`

Comment: What you're doing there is saying that for every `name` element in the node selected by the for-each loop, you wish to apply the most suitable template. What that will result in depends on the rest of your stylesheet.

Comment: i changed it to ` <xsl:value-of select="name" />` but doesn't work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many parts. `zoo/zootier` in `zootier` context is not probably what you want. You probably don't need any `for-each` there. Having a sample xml would help.

Also, `title` element should be a child of `head`, but this is not your immediate problem.

**EDIT:** One of the possibilities to handle `zootier`

```
  <xsl:template match="zootier">
    <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
    <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::zootier)">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Just noticed that `zoo/zootier` for-each thing as well. I thought maybe he had a recurring nested structure but he probably misunderstood the contextual stuff.

Comment: Not entirely impossible, but the first template matching `zoo` and referring to `zootier` children makes it rather curious coincidence.

Comment: I added some part of my XML file

Comment: @BabakBst, just removing `for-each` lines (opening and closing) will get you closer to the desired result (but it still will not be it, you may put some effort of your own into it).

Comment: @Michael:Do you mean that I should use only e.g:`<xsl:value-of select="name"/>`. I did it but ,doesn't work :(

Comment: I see no `value-of` in your xsl. If you want to use it, it should be `<xsl:value-of select="name/text()" />`, I think.